# Best Practices Using Tokens Returned by a Third-Party IdP with Cognito JS SDK?

Tags: javascript, authentication, jwt, amazon-cognito, idp

I am working on a web application that uses AWS Cognito Identity Provider to manage our users. We are also using Cognito's JavaScript SDK to authenticate users on the front end, periodically check that they have an active user session, and automatically handle their tokens (refreshing them periodically, etc.). We are now looking to provide users the ability to sign-in with a third-party SAML IdP (namely Okta) and have successfully connected the service to one of our Cognito User Pools. **However, where I am stuck is that I'm not sure what's the best way to use the id and access tokens returned to the application once the user has successfully logged in through the third-party IdP.**

With the current way our system is setup, our users enter their username and password during the login process, that information gets sent to Cognito via the SDK, Cognito and the SDK proceed through an authentication flow, and at the end, we are able to create a user object within the SDK to periodically check that the user has an active session open. The user's tokens are also completely handled by the SDK in this situation as well -- no need to manually refresh anything.

However, I'm not sure how to achieve this same functionality with just the tokens returned from the third-party IdP. Do we now have to write code to manually refresh the user's tokens, or is there a way to create a Cognito user object with just the tokens, and allow Cognito to automatically manage the tokens as normal?

**Some things I'm looking into**:

- I believe there are OAuth 2.0 token endpoints from which you can request and refresh tokens, based on [this article](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/token-endpoint.html). I am imagining that, if I can't leverage the SDK anymore, I will have to write code that periodically makes calls to these endpoints to get new user tokens. Is this a correct assumption, and is this standard practice?
- We have also considered creating a new Cognito user in the SDK using the person's email (from the id token payload) and User Pool ID to hopefully mimic the functionality we're looking for (keep track of the user's session, and possibly assist in the token refresh process). But it's not clear yet if this will actually work.

**TL;DR**: We're getting id and access tokens from a third-party IdP into our application, but aren't sure what the best practice is for using them, and if there's a way to have our JavaScript Cognito SDK manage them for us (automatically refreshing, etc.).

Comment: I'm also looking for an answer to this, can we use the cognito sdk to do actions on users managed by third-party idp's. Although I was able to set up a working app-client and sing-in using a hosted UI, I am not able to authenticate an external idp user with the SDK.